# How can I integrate Google Plus with iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to integrate google plus in my application,but I dont know from where to start,so if any one having idea about this please reply me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Google plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

Comment: actually I am looking for sample code.can you help me for that?

Comment: I ain't a objective-C developer, but check out on google if you could find a objective-C library for accessing the Google+ API, otherwise you will have to call the REST endpoints directly

Comment: For a simple signin and share snippet i wrote this code https://github.com/NasirMalik/GooglePlusShare

Comment: @NaXir Do you know how you can get the Sign In to happen within a UIWebView within the application rather than using Safari?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff i read the documentation and there wasn't any such option to login via webView. It will take u to the mobile safari or Google+ app if present on your device.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this as the basis -> https://developers.google.com/+/api/

1) Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console and request for an API key for yourself to be able to access google plus.

2) Then, check the "Fetching JSON Over HTTP" part in [this link](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) for how to integrate google plus into your iOS app. It worked for me. However, google currently gave only GET permission, so I don't think we can post updates using this to googleplus, sadly.

3) Then, your code might look like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}?key={your-api-key}"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the G+ iOS integration page:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ios

You can find examples on how to integrate your app with the G+ SDK, how to add a "Sign in with Google+" button, and how to get user information.

For a complete sample you can checkout the "PhotoHunt" sample application:
https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample code to start with. You can share a text and an image url etc via this code.

[Try this](https://github.com/NasirMalik/GooglePlusShare)