# Google Plus sharing, like button from ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to iPhone apps development, I want share and like button on google plus for my application, searched in web, but i got many links were pointing to developer.google.com etc. from there i downloaded SDK, but am not able to write code for that.

Please give some example code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Plus may be popular with Android but with iOS no one has Google Plus. On iOS we have a choice between Facebook, Twitter, and Google and no one chooses Google.

Answer (score 1):

there is a post here, which describes what you plan to do...

[How can I integrate Google Plus with iPhone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871991/how-can-i-integrate-google-plus-with-iphone-sdk)