# IOS GooglePlus Itegration Error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am getting compilation error when adding google plus sdk for lgoin with app.Screenshot is attached with this post.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871991/how-can-i-integrate-google-plus-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook

Answer (score 0):

As Per your description , you include GooglePlus third party library to your project file. So you have to set library path to project setting.

```
Step to edit project Setting:

1) Select your project at top -> Target -> Build setting-> Search path -> library search path

2)double click on Library search Path -> click + -> "$(SRCROOT)/ThirdPartyLibraryFolderName")
```

`Note:` Right click on project file and select open in finder. This opened file is a root directory . For example , this opened folder have folder like ShaDevice/GooglePlus/libGooglePlus.a means , you have to set library path as `"$(SRCROOT)/ShaDevice/GooglePlus/"`

Comment: i added this thing all ready but it's not work ,any other suggestion please

Comment: I think ,Now You have GooglePlus library file on documents folder. You have to move those file to project file root directroy(folder which contain your `projectname.xcodeproj` file).

Comment: NO Google Plus Library in inside my project file but it's not working.can please help me by telling that .What is the mean of GooglePlus/libGooglePlus.a (2 slices) (It's shows xcode warning)