# Google Plus Sharing from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I need to share users posts from my iphone app to google+. I did facebook and twitter share.

Does google+ have an API for this? Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link for the API of Google plus:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/

& here is the link where u can find help for sharing in google plus
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.0

```
import SafariServices
```

then add the delegate

```
<SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>
```

use this below code in the share button

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string:"https://plus.google.com/share")
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "url", value: "https://myexamplepagetoshare.com")
urlComponents?.queryItems = [queryItem]
let url = urlComponents?.url
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
safariVC.delegate = self
self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the simple G+ share that's available now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of sharing the posts on google plus is to first include its GPPShare.h file in xcode and then extend the .h file with GPPShareDelegate
And then write this code in the IBAction method

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
// This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
// item you're sharing.
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"Share" description:@"sharing" thumbnailURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9p3n1vJmZ1rexr16o1_400.jpg"]];
[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"rest=1234567"];
[shareBuilder open];
```

and also implement GPPShareDelegate method which is helpful in order to detect the successful sharing

```
 - (void)finishedSharing:(BOOL)shared
  {    if (shared) {
      NSLog(@"User successfully shared!");
   } else {
   NSLog(@"User didn't share.");
 }
```

Comment: when i implement this method.. I got  a console output that i have to sign in first. How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Right now they don't have any API I think.They are soon going to introduce .I hope help you.
But not now.

Comment: This doesnt seems to be proper answer.You must have added it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You use the Google+ share link:
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

> "The share link is intended for native client applications... and
>   others who may not be able to use the +1 or share button"

Answer (score 0):

I integrated Google plus sharing. Please see this code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0bwtzgbpobsjkq/Share.zip?dl=0