# Sharing on Google+ on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-plus

I understand there is a [developer portal for Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads), but I'm not sure how I can use this stuff to implement a +1 button within my iOS app. I want something simple, just like how ShareKit does it with facebook and twitter, but for Google+. How would I get started with this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: Ya I already linked to that, the question is how do I use that.

Comment: Read Google's documentations maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Google+ only provides a [JavaScript based +1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/). If you would like to +1 URLs from within your iOS app <s>you should star [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=50)</s>.
EDIT: The issue is marked as "Fixed" now, but with a solution that probably won't help for iOS apps.

Update: Google now has a [Google+ Platform for iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/).

Comment: That feature request has been marked as "Fixed" with a solution that I don't think helps iOS apps. But I think this is exactly what the OP is looking for: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/