# iOS: Possible to send or post message in Google Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus

In google plus, is there an API to send a message or submit a post in iOS to Google Plus?.. I had already tried reading the google documentation but haven't seen anything that does this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

OK.. I got it.. It's on their documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/api/.

Just right after the Google+ API section there's a note that says:

```
Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write data using the Google+ APIs, but you can use the Google+ share link.
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

> "The share link is intended for native client applications... and
>   others who may not be able to use the +1 or share button"