# Sharing images in Google+ using iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Here i'm working with Google+ integration in IOS Apps..

I have gone through the Guidelines at link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share

And I have **succeeded** in the following aspect.

-->>**Sharing Text**.

-->>**Sharing URLs**.

-->>**Sharing App(Google+ App) icon and Description**  [Using deep linking].

But I have **stuck** in the following aspect.

-->>**Sharing an Local or URL Image**.

so..is there any possibility to share an image from iPhone app through Google+.

Please help me...

**Thanks In Advance**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these discussions it is not possible yet:

[iOS: Possible to send or post message in Google Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105949/ios-possible-to-send-or-post-message-in-google-plus)

Comment: I am not implemented Google+ before...but from above posts no possibility is visible...

Answer (score 2):

you may use -(id) setURLToShare: (NSURL *)urlToShare

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/protocol_g_p_p_share_builder-p#a0f2e350ef29af0eb3ed4771c12e54925

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks But...It's not working for local images......even we pass an url which consist an image..it displaying both url and image in sharing panel....but i need only image...