# Sharing an image in LinkedIn integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

We can share a **message**(text) through **LinkedIn integration** in **iPhone Apps.**....

But Is there any possibility to share a **local image** or **url image** through **LinkedIn integration** in **iPhone Apps**......?

**Thanks In Advance**.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410986/how-to-post-an-image-to-a-linkedin-account-using-objective-c-code-on-ios

Comment: If you are able then let me know..

Comment: it is Possible @Rajneesh071 ...But the Limitations are...-->Not supported for local images..-->Not supported for high memory url images.

Comment: I did not implemented it yet,,. just made a search for you..

Comment: so just implement it and let me know..i will make it answer of your question..L)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no.I was able to send text to LinkedIn via share kit . But I was not unable to upload
image to LinkedIn. 
So, I think it is not possible.

Comment: @Vishal.. is it possible to Share an Image in Google+ integration..   See My Another Question in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872759/sharing-images-in-google-using-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2):

**Any how i got a relative solution...**

**Sharing an image in LinkedIn integration in iPhone---->**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
OAMutableURLRequest *request = 
[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                   token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];

NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility", 
                        statusTextView.text, @"comment",[[NSDictionary alloc]
                                                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         @"description goes here",@"description",
                                                         @"www.google.com",@"submittedUrl",
                                                         @"title goes here",@"title",
                                                         @"http://economy.blog.ocregister.com/files/2009/01/linkedin-logo.jpg",@"submittedImageUrl",nil],@"content", nil];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

[request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

Comment: But the Limitations are...-->Not supported for local images..-->Not supported for high memory url images.

Comment: @AshokKumarIOS...I know this method...& also its limitation.That's why I am not suggested you by this way...& simple advice you that it is not possible dude.

Comment: @AshokKumarS, I used your code but Image is not shown when I open my account in the browser.