# share content on linkedIn without using OAMutableURLRequest in iOS using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Is there any other way to share content like Images, URL, Text on LinkedIn without using OAMutableURLRequest in the iOS application using Objective-c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing an image in LinkedIn integration in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891716/sharing-an-image-in-linkedin-integration-in-iphone)

Comment: Again in this link, it is implemented using OAMutableURLRequest. Is there any other way except using OAMutableURLRequest to share text on LinkedIn?

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin try this

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this link to share content on linkedin: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth