# Google+ API Yet?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

I have checked other old Stackoverflow questions but they don't seem to help as they are outdated. I want to be able for the user to post on their Google+ wall/stream or whatever. Kind of like the Facebook Connect/Facebook iOS sdk. Is there one available similar to Google+, I don't mean ShareKit or anything I mean an OFFICIAL Google+ API and is there a developer website where I can sign up?

Comment: What makes you think the other questions are outdated? I see plenty of pointers to [the developer page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) and little reason to think that page is no longer the definitive source of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of google Developers site: [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)

You can easily integrate REST into an iOS project.

Comment: like Facebook,does it provide a kind of tutorial for iOS i only see Java there.... also where can i create a google+ app and register as a developer

Comment: If you are referring to the code on the page, that isnt java. That is a RESTful webservice. Basically you call a HTTP Method and a response is returned via JSON. I would take a look at this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework) to help you get going in the right direction.

Comment: There's also a client library for Objective-C (iOS) on the downloads page: https://developers.google.com/+/downloads - you can check that out for example code. Please note, though, that creating posts is still not possible! The API is read-only!

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest Google SDK project source code for Objective C:

```
svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```