# Google+ integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google plus api for posting on wall like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

In my application i want to integrate Google+. But i didn't get any API'S. If any one knows reagrding this.Kindly share with me.
                                  Thanks in advance.