# How to post message to google plus like Facebook?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

How to post text message to google plus wall using google plus api access token ?
I need to use multiple user login to google plus.

Comment: Here is how you need to do it.
Refer post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Google+ API. Here's the [link to the wrapper for iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/).