# Google plus multiple authentication possible in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, google-plus

Is there possible in google plus multiple Authentication ?

I used google plus api authentication and i cant post any message on google plus wall .

Comment: Can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: After successful authenticationticating you will get `auth` you can use this to all apis

Comment: can you show me api post message to google plus wall ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/7860636/1597744

Comment: Any Google plus api for posting on wall like Facebook ?